# Magento 1.9 - Custom Attribute - input_renderer / frontend_input_renderer not going into database

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, extensions, renderer

I'm creating an attribute like this

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();
$entityTypeId = 'catalog_product';
$installer->addAttribute($entityTypeId, 'ask_a_pharmacist', array(
    'group'             => 'SEO',
    'label'             => 'Ask A Pharmacist',
    'note'              => "Add lots of rows",
    'type'              => 'text',
    'input'             => 'textarea',
    'input_renderer'     => 'categoryatribute/adminhtml_helper_jcf',
    'default'           => '{"controls":{"locked":true,"maxrows":-1,"fields":["question","answer","author","date"]},"data":[]}',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,));
$installer->endSetup();
```

And the attribute is created, but the catalog_eav_attribute value remains null for this attribute. If I manually update frontend_input_renderer in the database to categoryatribute/adminhtml then it works fine, but not until then.

I need it working without this extra step but can't figure out what I need to change.

Here's my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
         <updates>
              <categoryatribute>
                    <file>innoxcategoryatribute.xml</file>
              </categoryatribute>
         </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
<modules>
    <Innox_CategoryAtribute>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
    </Innox_CategoryAtribute>
</modules>
 <global>
    <helpers>
        <categoryatribute>
            <class>Innox_CategoryAtribute_Helper</class>
        </categoryatribute>
    </helpers>   
    <models>
        <categoryatribute>
            <class>Innox_CategoryAtribute_Model</class>
        </categoryatribute>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <categoryatribute>
            <class>Innox_CategoryAtribute_Block</class>
        </categoryatribute>
    </blocks>    
    <resources>
        <add_category_attribute_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Innox_CategoryAtribute</module>
                <class>Innox_CategoryAtribute_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_setup>
        <add_category_attribute_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_write>
        <add_category_attribute_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, solved this.

My /Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
class Innox_CategoryAtribute_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
```

to

```
class Innox_CategoryAtribute_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup
```

And in my SQL file,

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
```

to

```
$installer = $this;
```